# How can I disable auto spelling for certain words in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spell-check

I am working in Excel and I'm testing it with various values in the cells. Whenever I insert the word **`Cafe`**. Excel changes it automatically to **`Café`**

I don't want this.

Is there any way I can disable this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Excel 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/turn-automatic-corrections-on-or-off-HP005201718.aspx)
- [Excel 2007](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/automatically-correct-spelling-and-insert-text-and-symbols-by-using-words-in-a-list-HA010099772.aspx)
- Excel 2010

  File, Options ... Proofing (see below for your example)

  [image]